# Publish in VS2015 get error message for missing pubxml file

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I get the project form other person. After I modified I used the publish and select the custom option. I got the following an error. I think the project still looking the old file which the person created and didn't give me.  Would someone tell me how can I change the issue.

There is the error message.

```
Copying file My Project\PublishProfiles\WC.pubxml to obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\My Project\PublishProfiles\WCOW.pubxml failed. Could not find file 'My Project\PublishProfiles\WCOW.pubxml'
```

Comment: have you tried to delete the obj folder? (make a backup first)

Comment: @FabioBelz which folder I need to delete?